# How to modify value in NSArray object?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I want to modify value in NSArray at index 0.

Here is sample program

```
NSArray *test = @[@"abc",@"rec",@"myPM"];
NSLog (@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:0]);
test[0]=@"001";
NSLog (@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Here I am getting lot of errors. please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an NSMutableArray

And with this method :

```
[yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:INDEX withObject:OBJECT].
```

Comment: hi, i have modified program like NSMutableArray *test = @[@"abc",@"rec",@"myPM"];
NSLog (@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:0]);
[test replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"001"];
NSLog (@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:0]);       but still getting error like  stray '@' in program , left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect

Comment: Try this : 

NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc", @"rec", @"myPM", nil];
NSLog (@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:0]);
[test replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"001"];
NSLog (@"%@",[test objectAtIndex:0]);